# Error while installing swig 3.0.0 in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, swig

I am getting the following error while I install swig 3.0.0 in buntu .Can anyone please help me?

```
Installing SWIG executable
Installing /usr/local/bin/swig
/home/irfan/swig_pcre/swig-3.0.0/Tools/config/install-sh: swig does not exist.
make: *** [install-main] Error 1
```

Comment: Can you add the content of install-sh ? Have you checked the paths?

Comment: You probably forgot to run `make`.

Answer (score 2):

Try running

```
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

I had this same error until I ran all three commands in a row.

Comment: Don't run `make` with `sudo` as it's unnecessary and might cause trouble when cleaning the source root of build files.